# Solve $T(n) = (T(\frac{n}{2}))^3 , T(1) = 2$

Tags: functions

Solve $T(n) = (T(\frac{n}{2}))^3 , T(1) = 2$

Well, I'm not sure how to approach this properly. can anyone help me out?

I've tried $T(1) = (T(0.5))^3 = 2$

But that doesn't help me much.

Find: $\Theta$ of the function.

Comment: $T(n)$ will only be defined for powers of $2$.

Comment: @NP-hard So I figured out that $T(2) = 8, T(4) = 2^9$, how can I continue with your hint for $T(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your equations only define what $T(2^k)$ is equal to for $k\in\mathbb Z$, since

$$\begin{align}T(2)&=T(1)^3=8\\
T(4)&=T(2)^3=8^3=512\\
T(8)&=T(4)^3=512^3\\
\vdots&\end{align}$$

For $x\notin\{2^k| k\in \mathbb Z\}=A$, you cannot (from the given data) calculate $T(x)$.

For example, you can define $T(x)=0$ on all $x\notin A$, and the condition is satisfied, but you can also define $T(x)=1$, and the condition will still be satisfied.

Comment: I see, thanks, what can I conclude about the Asymptotically tight barrier from what you've written?

Answer (score 1):

$$T(n)=2^{3^k}$$ for $n=2^k$ , $k=0,1,2,\cdots$ does the job.

Comment: I see, and how can I write it with $\Theta$ sign? I understand that it is exponential. can I just say that the answer would be $\Theta 2^{3^k}$?

Comment: Do you mean the growth rate ?

Comment: Yes. Asymptotically tight barrier. $\Theta$

Comment: I would suggest $\Theta=O(2^n)$. Note that $T(n)$ grows double-exponential, but $n$ grows exponential.

Comment: I see. thank you Peter!

Comment: after some more thought, your answer is not correct. The answer is $\Theta(2^{n ^ {log3}})$. I can provide a full solution if u want.

Answer (score -2):

**The answer is** $\Theta(2^{n ^ {log3}})$

[image]

Comment: @TravisJ I've edited.